# Couldn't find index page for 'ploneconf.site' (maybe misspelled?)

Tags: python, plone, plone-5.x

Hi i am following the mastering plone6 training. On:https://training.plone.org/5/mastering-plone/index.html#mastering-plone-label

I am trying to install plone on my computer and i am following these instructions for that: https://training.plone.org/5/plone_training_config/instructions.html

When I run the command to start building: `./bin/buildout` it builds just fine but after a while building stops with this error: `Couldn't find index page for 'ploneconf.site' (maybe misspelled?)` I already saw a thread with something similar but the things given there did not solve it my guess is that the problem is somewhere in the  buildout.cfg of the original training repo: this one https://github.com/collective/training_buildout/tree/plone6. So the buildout.cfg/repo might be outdated but I have not found a new one.

hope someone has a solution.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is Fixed the issue   is fixed the problem was that the buildout repo was to bloaded and oudated this is now fixed.